# Decoding UDP Data with Node_pcap

Tags: node.js, udp, pcap

I am trying to build quick nodejs script to look at some data in my network. Using [node_pcap](https://github.com/node-pcap/node_pcap) I manage to decode almost everything but the payload data that is end through the UDP protocol. This is my code (fairly basic but gives me the headers and payloads)

```
const interface = 'en0';
let filter = 'udp';
const pcap = require('pcap'),
  pcap_session = pcap.createSession(interface, filter),

  pcap_session.on('packet', function (raw_packet) {
    let packet = pcap.decode.packet(raw_packet);
    let data = packet.payload.payload.payload.data;
    console.log(data.toString()); // not full data
  });
```

When I try to print data using `toString()` method, it gives me most of the data but the beginning. I have something like this printed :

`Li?��ddn-�*ys�{"Id":13350715,...` I've cut the rest of the data which is the rest of the JSON.

But I am suspecting that the bit of data that I can't read contain some useful info such has how many packet, offset packet and so on..

I manage to get a part of it from the buffer from a payload :
`00 00 00 01 52 8f 0b 4a 4d 3f cb de 08 00 01 00 00 00 04 a4 00 00 26 02 00 00 26 02 00 00 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 09 2d 00 00 00 00 f3 03 01 00 00 2a 00 02 00 79 00 05 73 01 d2`

Although I have an idea of what kind of data it can be I have no idea of its structure.

Is there a way that I could decode this bit of the buffer ? I tried to look at some of the buffer method such as `readInt32LE`, `readInt16LE` but in vain. Is there some reading somewhere that can guide me through the process of decoding it?

[Edit] The more I looked into it, the more I suspect the data to be BSON and not JSON, that would explain why I can read some bit of it but not everything. Any chance someone manage to decode BSON from a packet ?

Answer (score 1):

#### How does the library know which packet decoder to use?

It starts at Layer 2 of the TCP/IP stack by identifying which protocol is used https://github.com/node-pcap/node_pcap/blob/master/decode/pcap_packet.js#L29-L56

```
switch (this.link_type) {
case "LINKTYPE_ETHERNET":
    this.payload = new EthernetPacket(this.emitter).decode(buf, 0);
    break;
case "LINKTYPE_NULL":
    this.payload = new NullPacket(this.emitter).decode(buf, 0);
    break;
case "LINKTYPE_RAW":
    this.payload = new Ipv4(this.emitter).decode(buf, 0);
    break;
case "LINKTYPE_IEEE802_11_RADIO":
    this.payload = new RadioPacket(this.emitter).decode(buf, 0);
    break;
case "LINKTYPE_LINUX_SLL":
    this.payload = new SLLPacket(this.emitter).decode(buf, 0);
    break;
default:
    console.log("node_pcap: PcapPacket.decode - Don't yet know how to decode link type " + this.link_type);
}
```

Then it goes upper and tries to decode the proper protocol based on the flags it finds in the header https://github.com/node-pcap/node_pcap/blob/master/decode/ipv4.js#L12-L17 in this particular case for the [IPv4 protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4)

```
IPFlags.prototype.decode = function (raw_flags) {
    this.reserved = Boolean((raw_flags & 0x80) >> 7);
    this.doNotFragment = Boolean((raw_flags & 0x40) > 0);
    this.moreFragments = Boolean((raw_flags & 0x20) > 0);
    return this;
};
```

Then in your case it would match with the udp protocol https://github.com/node-pcap/node_pcap/blob/master/decode/ip_protocols.js#L15

```
protocols[17]  = require("./udp");
```

Hence, If you check https://github.com/node-pcap/node_pcap/blob/master/decode/udp.js#L32 the packet is automatically decoded and it exposes a `toString` method

```
UDP.prototype.toString = function () {
    var ret = "UDP " + this.sport + "->" + this.dport + " len " + this.length;
    if (this.sport === 53 || this.dport === 53) {
        ret += (new DNS().decode(this.data, 0, this.data.length).toString());
    }
    return ret;
};
```

#### What does this mean for you?

In order to decode a udp(any) packet you just call the high level api `pcap.decode.packet(raw_packet)` and then call `toString` method to display the decoded body payload

```
pcap_session.on('packet', function (raw_packet) {
    let packet = pcap.decode.packet(raw_packet);
    console.log(packet.toString());
});
```